# How to handle the case when KKT condition is always false for this toy case?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, operations-research, karush-kuhn-tucker

For the following simple problem:
$$\begin{aligned}
\min_x & (x-2)^2\\
s.t. \ \ & x^2=0\\
&x^2 \le 0
\end{aligned}$$

Since there is only one feasible point $x=0$, the answer is obvious. But when writting the KKT condition as:
$$L=(x-2)^2+vx^2+wx^2$$
$\partial_x L=2(x-2)+2vx+2wx=0$
if $x=0$, we have $-4=0$, it obviously wrong. I think the solution should fulfill all KKT point. Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the KKT conditions.

> Suppose that $x^*$ is *regular*, that is, the gradients of the LHS functions of the constraints which are satisfied as an equality are linearly independent, and suppose that $x^*$ is a local optimum. Then, $x^*$ satisfies the KKT conditions.

In your case, $x^* = 0$ is irregular. Both constraints are satisfies as an equality, and for both the derivative at $x = 0$ is zero. The set $\{0, 0\}$ is clearly not linearly independent.

Both KKT points and irregular points may be optimal, and their union is your set of candidates.

Comment: Note that there are many other constraint qualification hypotheses that can be used in place of the linear independence constraint qualification (LICQ) that you've stated here.  However, $x=0$ isn't regular under any of those conditions.

Comment: @BrianBorchers you are, of course, right.